# Veloute consistency after being refrigereted

Tags: french-cuisine, roux

Not been into French cuisine much so I started to try to make the mother sauces for some fun.  I cooked up some chorizo in clarified butter and used that fat to make a roux, blonded it, then stirred in some chicken stock.  Turned out to have an excellent velvety texture.  What will happen to the consistency of the sauce after being in the fridge for a night?  Also, my sauce had the consistency of tempered chocolate, is this on par or thicker than what would be considered 'normal'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sauce will thicken when cooled. And as for consistency... It really depends on individual taste. The usual test is "When you did a spoon into the sauce, does the sauce coat the spoon upon removal?"

However, I like my sauces a bit thicker. Tempered choco. is about my tastes, however alot of people would like it a bit thinner. It's all a matter of taste.

Also note, the sauce will thicken on cooling, but will return to it's chocolatey consistency upon reheating.

Comment: i was mainly curious about the sauce's ability to be reconstituted to its previous consistency. good to hear that it won't be a problem. also, i highly suggest trying out using the fat from whatever sausage you use in your gumbo to make your roux.  delicious! :)

Comment: +1 @wootscootinboogie: Also, you should cover the velouté with cling film or parchment paper to prevent the formation of a nasty coating on top. This coating forms by evaporation, and both the cling film and parchment paper prevent this. When reheating, the coating will form blotches in the sauce that nobody wants to eat.

Comment: ah, that's the essence of the stack exchange network right there